# Run Disk Cleanup When fsutil returns under a certain size

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-scripting

I would like a fully automated way of running disk cleanup when fsutil volume diskfree c: returns under, lets say, 50gb. Currently, I have used cleanmgr /sageset:1 and stored my settings, so the process is half automated. But when it returns the amount of space free, is there any way for windows to read this. Keep in mind this will be in a batch file, so I cannot manually view this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want the code to be served with a cup of tee or coffee? StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to try it on your own first and when stuck, come back here, show your efforts, describe precisely what you want to achieve and what you actually get. Without any research by yourself this question is likely going to be closed here.

Comment: REM Run cleanup
IF EXIST %SystemRoot%\SYSTEM32\cleanmgr.exe START /WAIT cleanmgr /sagerun:100. I also run fsutil volume diskfree c:. I know exactly what I want to do with this. I don't need anyone to write my code, but I would like to know if it is possible to get the result of free space on the c: drive for further use.

Comment: Please post additional information by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38509133/edit) the question rather than a comment; code looks terrible in comments but can be nicely and legibly formatted in the main post...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "pad=000000000000000"
set "NeededSpace=%pad%4294967296"
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%x in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value'
) do for %%y in (%%x) do set "FreeSpace=%pad%%%y"
if "%FreeSpace:~-15%" geq "%NeededSpace:~-15%" echo Drive has at least 4 GB free space.
```